# How to append CSS from a variable in CSS or HTML file? Angular 4+

Tags: javascript, angular

Is that possible to append `CSS` from a variable. for example

```
var myHtml = "<div>My example html</div>";

// in html i can do this

<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>
```

But what if I have `CSS` stored in variable. like below:-

```
var myCss = ".exampleClass {margin: 0;width: 100%;}";
```

How can I add this css variable in my `CSS` file OR in `HTML` as a working css?

I'm using Angular 4+ but even JavaScript solution also appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply insert a new `<style>` tag into your page using JavaScript:

```js
var myCss = ".exampleClass {margin: 0;width: 100%;color:blue}";

var style = document.createElement("STYLE");
style.innerText = myCss;
document.body.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<div class="exampleClass">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
`<div [style.width.%]="WidthValue" [style.marginTop.px]="marginTopValue"></div>`

where, in *.ts file, you are having value in a variable

```
WidthValue: number = 100;
marginTopValue: number = 0;
```

Adding one more way,

```
<div [ngStyle]="styleObject"></div>
```

where,

```
styleObject = {
  'width': '100px',
  'margin-top': '10px'
}
```

Comment: can't because i have lots of CSS and css can be changed dynamically form backend.